# django override delete cascade for one time

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Is there an option for to make sure that a model instance does not have any related objects?
i.e, if the Person object has any related objects, I want this line

```
person.delete()
```

to raise an error.

And I don't want to modify `on_delete=models.CASCADE` for every foreign key. I need this protection only here, for any other case in my application (like django admin site) I do prefer the cascading behavior.

Comment: Do you try to overrife delete method from your model? check for your fk and others inside this method and call super(...).delete() to delete your model

Comment: I didn't override the delete method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this correspond to what you want?

```
has_related = False
for field in person.__class__._meta.get_fields():
    if field.is_relation:
        field_name = field.get_accessor_name()
        model_field = getattr(person, field_name)
        if not isinstance(model_field, models.Model) and model_field.all():
            has_related = True
            break

if not has_related:
    person.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks, why the use of get_cache_name() for field objects? I'm getting an AttributeError

Comment: I updated my post with `get_accessor_name()` instead of `get_cache_name()`. We use this method to get the `XXX_set` (or else if modified) name of the related field. Where do you get your AttributeError ?